# Update com várias tabelas

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Boas, este é um problema complexo mas tentei po-lo da forma mais simplificada possivel para melhor entenderem.
eu quero atualizar ou copiar todos os campos da coluna preço custo da tabela A para a coluna preço custo da tabela D.

---

```
     tabela A 
|coluna1|Coluna2|
|:-----|---------------:|
|Guid1 | preço custo    |




    tabela B
|coluna1|Coluna2|
|:-----|---------------:|
|Guid1 | itemkeyid1|
```

entre a tabela A e na tabela B o único elemento que conecta elas é a Guid1

---

```
tabela B
|coluna1|Coluna2|
|:-----|---------------:|
|Guid1 | itemkeyid1|


tabela C
|coluna1|Coluna2|
|:-----|---------------:|
|itemkeyid1 | guid2 |
```

entre a tabela B e tabela C o único elemento que conecta elas é itemkeyid1

---

```
tabela C
|coluna1|Coluna2|
|:-----|---------------:|
|itemkeyid1 | guid2 |


tabela D
|coluna1|Coluna2|
|:-----|---------------:|
|guid2 | preço custo |
```

entre a tabela C e na tabela D o único elemento que conecta elas é a Guid2

---

relembrando que o meu objetivo é passar os dados da coluna preço custo da Tabela A para a coluna preço custo da tabela D, como posso executar este update ?

Answer (score 0):

Não tenho experiência com o BD que você está utilizando mas segue uma sugestão para testes:

```
update TabelaD d
inner join TAbelaC c on c.guid2 = d.guid2
inner join TabelaB b on b.itenkeyid1 = c.itemkeyid1
inner join TabelaA a on a.guid1 = b.guid1
set d.precocusto = a.precocusto
```

Comment: obrigado, era isso mesmo.